# Silverlight Sharepoint 2010 web part windows authentication

Tags: silverlight, sharepoint-2010, windows-authentication

I'm trying to authenticate my silverlight application to get windows user name, which then I use to get some further information. Have looked it up, but the answers I found were about configuring the web service to get it. Is there a way, to get windows credentials strictly in Silverlight? I cannot find .Credentials, the only thing I see is .ClientCredentials, but apparently it doesn't show the required information. I am getting the string "System.ServiceModel.Security.UserNamePasswordClientCredential". It actually allows me to set up the name, not retrieve it. Also there is a web service called authentication.asmx, but as before it applies to other purposes. Neither do I have any web service I could reference to and configure them. Or am I missing something? Perhaps I can retrieve the windows credential by NTLM or Kerberos? I am using Visual Web Developer 2010 Express with Silverlight 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Experience is that the Membership framework that is present in the asp.net world is not available in silverlight. In order to achieve something similar I had to implement a web service (WCF) that was directed at the domain's active directory (ldap) server. Silverlight is a very strict framework in terms of interoperability, its good for security but has some limitations.

I am not sure about your level of knowledge of the active directory but here is a link that deal with a lot of the possible operations and has sample C# code to go along.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C#40a

Comment: So it looks like there's no other option than to deploy a web service to do it. Is it possible then to make it work in sharepoint environment, or it has to be external?

Comment: I have never done authentication within a share point environment but this link seems to say that it is possible http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcauthentication.authentication.aspx It seems like you have within sharepoint predefined services that you can implement/override. hope this helps.